# For Loops to iterate over id for each item in column

Tags: python

I want to iterate over a dataframe for each id and for each fruit, so that for each fruit there is a the other fruits associated with that id and the prices of both.

I've tried using itertuples but then the tuples are the new column names and the price is the value:

```
for line in df4.itertuples():
    df4[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]
df4
```

[example and expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fvhh.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please also show some minimal coding effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to avoid for loops when using pandas Dataframe, which has much more efficient functions.

Here is one way to do so with pandas.merge:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        'fruit': ['apple', 'grape', 'pear', 'grape', 'apple', 'pear'],
        'price': [3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1]
    }).set_index('id')
    print(pd.merge(left=df, right=df, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)\
          [lambda df: df.fruit_x < df.fruit_y])
```

The output is then:

```
   fruit_x  price_x fruit_y  price_y
id                                  
1    apple        3   grape        4
1    apple        3    pear        2
1    grape        4    pear        2
2    grape        2    pear        1
2    apple        5   grape        2
2    apple        5    pear        1
```

This output is different than what appears in your screenshot, but matches your problem description: it yields all pairs of different fruits with same ID.
Also note that this code assumes that no fruit appears more than once with the same ID.

Comment: @sben33 just drop the "set_index".